# How to programmatically build a page and a form in the same page

Tags: 8, forms, page-controller

What I'd like to do is build a page with two things:

- On one half of the page, custom markup with data from Drupal.
- On the other half, a custom form also submitted to Drupal.

There are a lot of tutorials on how to programmatically build pages in D8 (create route, extend controller, return render array, etc.). There are also a lot of tutorials on how to programmatically build forms on D8 (create route, extend form base, return render array, etc.). However, I could not find any resource on how to build *both* onto the same page.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Jdrupal has the answer below. Additionally, if you are rendering the form using  FormBuilder, you don't need to create a route for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use the `formBuilder`, like this:

```
$render = [];
$render['elememt1'] = [
  '#type' => 'markup',
  '#markup' => t('Test'),
];
$render['element2'] = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\MY_MODULE\Form\MyFormClass');// The destination of your form.

return $render;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it fits to your project.

As a themer, I would create a form with `Form Api` in a custom module.

The I would create a custom block for this form :

```
src/Plugin/Block/HelloBlock.php
```

See here for a example :https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-blocks/create-a-custom-block

I would then create a twig template for the page (what you call "custom markup with data from Drupal"). And Then I would integrate the custom block with the form.